# Getting the array value of angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a list that looks like this:

```
Store 1
  Section A
  Section B
  and so on...
Store 2
  Section A
  and so on...
```

So I open a modal window to create a new store. I return the store when I close the window, and so far that's working great!

```
<div ng-repeat="store in global.user.company2.store">
```

I need to push the callback store to $scope.global.user.company2.store[?]

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (newStore) {
    // How do I get the IndexOf value of store?
    // This is one of the stores in the ng-repeat 
    $scope.global.user.company2.store[???].section.push(newStore)
}, function () {
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

The way I'm sending a selected store into the modal is with resolve

```
    $scope.createSection = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'createSection.html',
            controller: 'SectionModal',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    // $scope.radio.model === store
                    // $scope.radio.model2 === section
                    return $scope.radio;
                }
            }
        });
```

UPDATE: Here's a basic plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/UGN4niAO9nQETqhg8lxn
The radio model buttons aren't working. If you change resolve items to $scope.radio.model, the modal breaks. So I left it as is. I think maybe it has to do with the btn-radio being part of angular-ui-bootstrap?

Comment: can u make a fiddle?

Comment: I'll try to make one!

Comment: please post a plunker, here is an angular template to get you started: http://plnkr.co/edit/WprgipAdFBtxDKM6jogo?p=info

Comment: where's the piece that shows how user selects the store it's going to? Just need to put that store object reference into variable  something like `$scope.currentStore`. Then in `result` would be `$scope.currentStore.section.push(newStore)`

Comment: Thanks charlieftl! I have the currently selected store's name. I can display it in the modal. But I don't know the indexof value of it in the array of global.user.store. Right now it just uses radio buttons to select the store. The radio buttons are stores in global.user.stores (ng-repeat).

Comment: Is there a way to count the number of radio options in a given ng-model, perhaps? Like if I have 3 btn-radio buttons with ng-model="radio", can I count those somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When resolving your modal, box your returned object with the array index of the object.
For example:

```
 $modalInstance.close({ radio: $scope.radio, index: $scope.items.indexOf($scope.radio) } );
```

Then, when resolving your modal's promise, simply unbox your object:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem.radio;
      $scope.selectedIndex = selectedItem.index;
}, function () {});
```

See the Angular-Bootstrap [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) for more details.